# Loop through objects where an object contains further object[] and get Value

Tags: c#, reflection, iteration

I used Reflection to get all relevant information out of a Class Libary (.dll).
It returns a List of Object-Arrays, which I created

```
list.Add(args.Select(x => x.Value).toArray());
```

Each Object-Array contains a `System.Reflection.CustomAttributeTypedArgument`, object. My goal is to get all values of each `Object[]`.

```
foreach (var type in types)
{

    MethodInfo[] declaredMethods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

    foreach (var method in declaredMethods)
    {
        foreach (var test in method.CustomAttributes)
        {
            var args = test.ConstructorArguments;
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                if (args.Count > 0 && 
                    arg.ToString().Contains(Path.GetFileName(path)))
                {
                    list.Add(args.Select(x => x.Value).toArray());     
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far I got a structure where an object contains multiple object-arrays. These object-arrays contain the value i want to achieve. But I cant iterate over them, since I cant iterate over an object.

Comment: Are you aware that you are storing the `IEnumerable<T>` as one element of the constructed `new object[]`? So if your list only adds one item. the result is a list which contains 1 object array item, which contains one element that is the enumerable. You should use `list.Add(args.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());` to fix that.

Comment: I already did that, but if I want to print it out, there is just returned "System.Object[]". A further loop does not seem to work.

Comment: Please update your question with the loop you've tried. Also fix the `.ToArray()` in your question. This way it is up-to-date and we can have a better understanding how it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I added some further information.

Comment: Uh.... `list.Add(new object[] { args.Select(x => x.Value).toArray() });` instead of adding the `IEnumerable<T>` as one element, you're putting an array as one element. You didn't read my `list.Add(args.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());` well enough.  Lose the `{...}` object initializers.

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. In the case of "object[1] -> object[2] - Data" it works very well, thanks. But in the case with another step, it doesnt. How could I add another nested-loop in that case?

Comment: @Baflora you should probably create a recursive method for that, as probably you don't know how many levels of sub-arrays you can expect.

Comment: Thats a good idea, but i dont know which methods to call for going deeper into the structure. Im not really into the Reflection mechanics.